# Unable to update cookie information with a setter method

Tags: php, arrays, oop, cookies

This is my start of my `Cookie` class:

```
<?php
namespace Core;

use \App\Config;

class Cookie implements UserInformationInterface
{

    public static function start()
    {
        if (!isset($_COOKIE[Config::COOKIE_NAME])) {
            setcookie(Config::COOKIE_NAME, serialize(array()), time() + Config::COOKIE_TIME, '/', false, false);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static function set($array)
    {
        self::start();
        if (!empty($array)) {
            if ($_COOKIE[Config::COOKIE_NAME]) {
                $cookieArray = unserialize($_COOKIE[Config::COOKIE_NAME]);
            } else {
                $cookieArray = array();
            }

            foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
                $cookieArray[$key] = $value;
            }

            $_COOKIE[Config::COOKIE_NAME] = serialize($cookieArray);
            setcookie(Config::COOKIE_NAME, $_COOKIE[Config::COOKIE_NAME], time() + Config::COOKIE_TIME, '/', false, false);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

And my `sigininAction()` in my `Home` class contains these lines:

```
Cookie::set(array('remember' => 1));
header('Location: ' . Config::BASE_URL . 'user/dashboard/');
exit;
```

However, if I `var_dump($_COOKIE[Config::COOKIE_NAME])` once I reach `user/dashboard/`, I get the following, which is the default cookie value set in my `start()` method, and not the updated one that should be created with my `set()` method.:

```
string(6) "a:0:{}"
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? Please let me know if you need any more code.

Comment: Did you check your browser network tab on the response where it sets the cookie... you should probably see two Set-Cookie: in the raw header. First one is that default value, the second should be the serialized remember:1 value.

Comment: As a side... I am not spotting anything abnormal in your code. It looks like it should set two cookies for the first time, and browsers should accept the second cookie as the final result.

Comment: Thanks, that let me spot the problem. From all the testing and error checking I had the same cookie set in `/`, `/_MVC` and `/_MVC/local` that seemed to be getting read instead. Cleared them all manually and the code works fine.

Comment: Ah, heh... yes that would do it! Its a nice class, but personally I would use json ;) less cookie size.

Comment: I thought JSON, but decided "eh, a human's never going to need to read it". But if it's smaller, then that's better (assumed it would be bigger)!

Comment: Serialize: `a:1:{s:8:"remember";i:1;}` ... JSON: `{"remember":1}`.

Comment: @mpdc, you will surprised what mischievous humans read and write in their cookies. Your code could be abused to [inject PHP objects](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Object_Injection), and that may lead to a partial or full compromise of your application. If you only need to store arrays anyway, I suggest you go with JSON and save yourself future headaches.